# Exception on fetching the data from database

Tags: vb.net

```
Private Sub btnSearch_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnSearch.Click
        Dim data As DataRow

        Try
            OleDbDataAdapter1.Fill(Me.DataSet11.PAYMENT)
            data = DataSet11.PAYMENT.Rows.Find(txtpayment.Text)
            txtpayment.Text = data("CustomerIC")
            txtName.Text = data("CustomerName")
            txtadd.Text = data("CustomerAddress")
            txttel.Text = data("NoTel")
            If cKurung.AutoCheck = True Then
                cKurung.Checked = data("Baju Kurung")
                Quan1 = Convert.ToInt32(txtQ1.Text)
                Quan1 = data("Quantity1")
            End If

            If cKebaya.AutoCheck = True Then
                cKebaya.Checked = data("Baju Kebaya")
                Quan2 = Convert.ToInt32(txtQ2.Text)
                Quan2 = data("Quantity2")
            End If

            If cTudung.AutoCheck = True Then
                cTudung.Checked = data("Tudung")
                Quan3 = Convert.ToInt32(txtQ3.Text)
                Quan3 = data("Quantity3")
            End If

            If cSelendang.AutoCheck = True Then
                cSelendang.Checked = data("Selendang")
                Quan4 = Convert.ToInt32(txtQ4.Text)
                Quan4 = data("Quantity4")
            End If

            If cTelekung.AutoCheck = True Then
                cTelekung.Checked = data("Telekung")
                Quan5 = Convert.ToInt32(txtQ5.Text)
                Quan5 = data("Quantity5")
            End If

            If cAnakTudung.AutoCheck = True Then
                cAnakTudung.Checked = data("Anak Tudung")
                Quan6 = Convert.ToInt32(txtQ6.Text)
                Quan6 = data("Quantity6")
            End If
            txtQuan.Text = data("Quantity")
            txtPrice.Text = data("Price")

        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show("Invalid Customer IC", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
            txtpayment.Text = ""
            txtpayment.Focus()
            txtpayment.ReadOnly = False

        End Try
    End Sub
```

This is my code. Calling Quantity rather than Quantity1 it will throw error. For example, in other form i fill the quantity1 only but the others quantity i dont fill then when i want to find the data it will error.

Comment: **What does the error _say_?** Did you read it?

Comment: Error occured in **txtQ1.AutoCompleteCustomSource = data("Quantity1")** part ?

Comment: @SLaks it will say like this "Input string was not in a correct format."

Comment: @matzone i just edit new code.

Comment: Please learn to use the debugger. Also, please learn to include information in your questions here. "it will error" means nothing to anyone here but you, because you didn't tell us what "error" means. You need to be specific, and when you get an error tell us what that error is and include the **exact error message** you receive.

Comment: @user2387931 : Sorry, but I want to know .. what happen in **cKebaya.Checked = data("Baju Kebaya")** coz there's no **function data()** .. and is this have corelation with **[your another question]**(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16577101/failed-to-convert-parameter-value-from-a-string-to-a-int32-visual-studio-2010)

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem lies in one of those line that contains `Convert.ToInt32(txtQ.Text)` in which you are trying to convert a possibly invalid string to an integer. Consider using [Int32.TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) instead which eliminates the needs to handle the exceptions:

```
Dim result As Int32;

' Returns true if conversion was successful
If Int32.TryParse(txtQ1.Text, out result)  Then 
      Quan1 = result;
End If
```